# Xcode 7: is chasm between app tests and UI tests unbridgeable?

Tags: xcode, automated-tests, xcode7, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

Xcode 7† has a new way to test your UI directly, including a new testing target "iOS UI Testing Bundle" (or "OS X").

[image]

In the UI testing target, it appears there's no built-in access to the model or classes that comprise your App. E.g. `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` would not be callable from your UI tests.
This implies that "app tests" and "UI tests" exist across a possibly unbridgeable chasm.

As stated [here](https://medium.com/@larcus94/ui-testing-with-xcode-7-221d16bad276):

> The problem is that Xcode’s UI testing does not allow access to the actual app.

Questions:

1. Can this chasm be bridged? If so, how, in detail, with build and linker settings and possibly a working `xcodeproj` on github.
2. Where might a clear statement of this divide to be found, in Apple docs.

---

† At the time of writing, beta software.

Answer (score 7):

**Black-box Testing**

UI Testing is a [black-box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing) framework. You shouldn't have to know anything about the implementation of the code you are testing.

For example, you should only care that the value on a label changes, not that the controller passed the right data to the view. You can think of UI Testing from the **user of your app's** perspective. She doesn't care how your `ItemsViewController` works (or even that it exists), so why should the UI Tests?

**Getting it to "Work"**

That being said, I understand your frustration. It would be great if you could spin up a view controller and then tap around with UI Testing and making assertions. However, as of Beta 5 this is not possible.

What's interesting is that you can, however, create instances of your app's objects with a simple `@testable import ModuleName` at the top of your UI Tests. Note that you can't actually interact with it via the `.tap()`-like methods, as it's a `UI*` class, not a `XCUI*` one.

Consider `Donut` to be the application's module name.

```
import XCTest
@testable import Donut

class DonutUITests: XCTestCase {
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    override func setUp() {
        continueAfterFailure = false
        app.launch()
    }

    func testItemsViewController() {
        let controller = ItemsViewController()
        controller.addItemButton.tap() // <---- UIButton does not respond to tap()!
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's say you have an app with dynamic content. You want to manipulate the UI and then verify something that isn't visible on-screen.  Or, perhaps you need to verify a specified state before deciding which method to call, and that state is only known by querying an Objective-C method in the app code.  It's nice to have a mix of both ways of testing, without having to craft each view yourself.

Comment: Further to Teresa's comments, you might want to initialise your project to a certain state before performing UI tests.