# Xcode UI Testing - UITableView sections

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I want to use Xcode's UI Testing to count the number of sections in a tableview and the number of cells in each section. How can I do that?

Comment: Why not to use your datasource instead ?

Comment: 1. How can I access code from a UI test?
2. I want to make sure the sections are parsed correctly from the data source

Comment: just call tableview's numberOfSection and numberOfRows from your UI test class ... ?(Not sure if i am getting your question right)

Comment: I don't have access to the tableview from the UI test class

Comment: is it restricted or you don't know how to make it accessible ?

Comment: I don't know if it's even possible

Comment: it's very much possible i think

Comment: It's not possible to access the application code directly from the UI Testing target. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32076413/384110) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

As of Xcode 7, table view headers show as `Other` elements.

Here's what I did for a (grouped) table view in my app:

```
extension TableLayoutTests {

    func testHasMessagesGroup() {
        XCTAssert(app.tables.otherElements["MESSAGES"].exists)
    }

    func testHasMessageCell() {
        let header = app.tables.otherElements["MESSAGES"]
        let cell = app.tables.cells.elementBoundByIndex(1)
        XCTAssertGreaterThanOrEqual(cell.accessibilityFrame.minY, header.accessibilityFrame.maxY)
    }

    func testHasOtherMessageCell() {
        let header = app.tables.otherElements["MESSAGES"]
        let cell = app.tables.cells.elementBoundByIndex(2)
        XCTAssertGreaterThanOrEqual(cell.accessibilityFrame.minY, header.accessibilityFrame.maxY)
    }

}
```

Comment: Very creative, I like it

Answer (score 2):

Joe Masilotti is entirely correct in that application code cannot be accessed directly from the UI Test, though you can backchannel if you want to be out-of-style. Let's assume you don't.

Xcode's UI Testing framework has access to all of the Swift language along with the UI hierarchy of your app, but not access to the data layer; so you can do the following:

- Give the headers or footers of the tableview sections accessibilityIdentifiers that include an index component (e.g., photos.headers_0 , etc)
- Having done that, use conditionals to determine the number of sections
- Similarly, photos.section_0.cell_0 can be assigned in your data source, and an iterator + conditional can store the number of cells in section 0 or any other section.